# Why are there unused values for opcodes in .Net CIL?

Tags: .net, cil

CIL has a few double-byte instructions which I find really strange considering there are a lot of available single-byte instructions that are unused. Some specific examples are:

- `0x24` is unused between `0x23 ldc.r8` and `0x25 dup`
- `0xA6` through `0xB2` are unused between `0xA5 unbox.any` and `0xB3 conv.ovf.i1`

I only count 27 double-byte instructions and there are more gaps than this available.

I could kind of understand if it was an alignment issue, but many single-byte instructions are followed by 32 bit integers (5 bytes total) and several double-byte instructions are followed by 32 bit integers (6 bytes total) with one double-byte instruction followed by an 8 bit integer (3 bytes total). These are not aligned to any consistent boundary as far as I can tell.

For reference, I'm using the documentation on the System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes static fields https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes

Forgive me if this is the wrong Stack to ask on, I was torn between this and Software Engineering. Let me know if I should post there instead.

Comment: This work started long ago, well before it was ever envisioned to be used in .NET.  The odds that you'll hear from whomever worked on this twenty five years ago are not good.  Somewhat probable is that a very early prototype back in the Project42 days used them, but were cut later on.  Well, it isn't exactly like you need to know to use it.